# Objective-C async http request

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to create an async http request. Where to start? Can you give me some good links to start this? I want to learn it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]
```

See [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html

Comment: For you, also thanks the answer. I think, this answer is good if you want to create games.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party SDK like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) . It is very simple to use and come with some delegate methods. This is [how](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) you can use it. It is really useful as it provide a lot of features.