# Signalling an error from a method that returns an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, error-handling

I have a bit of an architecture problem. I have a method that returns an array based on data from a server.

```
NSArray *myStuff = [anObject getMyStuff];
```

Obviously the server can fail. What is the best way to cater for this? I was looking at how `performFetch:` works, but that has a `BOOL` as a return type. Can I have:

```
NSArray *myStuff = [anObject getMyStuff:&anError];
```

Comment: Name the method `retrieveMyStuff:` or the like;  `get` is a reserved prefix.   Yes, returning nil to signal an error and filling in the error parameter is just fine (note that you should deal with the fact that anError might be NULL, signaling that the caller is not interested in the error at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, as e.James suggested before, do a proper asynchronous handling, where the object, that performs the fetch, will call a method, if it was successful or another, if it failed.
There is an variant of this, that is used in the popular [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/): pass two blocks to the method, one for the failing case, one for the success case

This could look like this than:

```
[client shopsFeedForUserWithID:2 
                       success:^(id response) {
                           blockSelf.shops = [Shop shopsFromReponseDict:response];
                           [blockSelf.tableView reloadData];
                      } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                           //handle the error
                      }];
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: *it's up to you*.

Some of the Cocoa classes do use the simple pointer-to-error object that you describe. If you are loading data from a server, you may want to look at a more complex request/response system that handles [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297398/objetive-c-async-http-request) data.

Alternatively, if you are looking for a very simple solution, just return `nil` when the request fails.